# How does struct Node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr)) work?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, sizeof

I'm a C beginner, and I came across this code while trying to implement a linked list.

```
    struct Node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

The Node struct looks like this:

```
    struct Node {
        int data;
        struct Node *next;
    };
```

I'm trying to understand the first line. It seems as if `malloc(sizeof(*ptr))` already knows the contents of `ptr`. What exactly is happening on the left side and is it happening before malloc is called?

Comment: If you follow it through in terms of following the pointer it makes sense - it’s saying “get me space for something the size of struct Node”. If you make is self referential like that it is apparently safer. I think it’s a stupid way to write it because it’s not very clear. Everybody knows we want size of struct Node so I just write struct Node, but I guess that is the way it’s done.

Comment: @LEF Writing it this way protects against the name of type changing.

Comment: malloc return void*, I don't think it work. You should cast it to Node* type.

Comment: @ĐăngKhôi C allows converting to and from a `void *` without a cast.  C++ doesn't.

Comment: @dbush You can make the similar argument that `malloc(sizeof(struct Node))` protects against changing the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allocate a memory for an object of the type `struct Node` declared like

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

So in the call of malloc you need to specify the size of the memory to be allocated for an object of this type. The function malloc returns a pointer to the allocated memory.

So you can write

```
struct Node *ptr = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
```

On the other hand, the expression `*ptr` has the type struct Node. That is the declared pointer `ptr` has the pointer type `struct Node *` and dereferencing such a pointer like `*ptr` yields an expression of the type `struct Node`.

So you may rewrite the above record also like

```
struct Node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

because in this case `sizeof( struct Node )` is equivalent to `sizeof( *ptr )`.

That is the compiler needs to know the type of the operand of the operator `sizeof` that to determine the size of an object of that type.

Answer (score 4):

Only use paranthesis with `sizeof` if there's a *type* you'd like to know the size of. If you have an *expression*, like `*ptr`, it's enough to write:

```
struct Node *ptr = malloc(sizeof *ptr);         // <- no parenthesis
```

The expression `*ptr` dereferences the pointer so it becomes a `struct Node` and that's what the `sizeof` is returning the size for.

> [`sizeof`*`expression`*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) - Returns the size, in bytes, of the object representation of the type of expression. No implicit conversions are applied to expression.

It's the same size you get if you do:

```
struct Node *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); // <- parenthesis needed
```

but the first alternative is often preferable for clarity.

Answer (score 4):

> It seems as if `malloc(sizeof(*ptr))` already knows the contents of `ptr`.

Actually, it doesn't.  The `sizeof` operator doesn't actually evaluate its operand (unless it's a variable length array), it just looks at its type.  This means that `ptr` isn't actually dereferenced and is therefore a safe operation.